# Add history item to html browser history without changing page angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser-history, html5-history

I'm attempting to rewrite a small part of user history as soon as they visit my angular application.

Currently I'm attempting to change the last history item to a certain page once the app loads, however instead of just changing the history, the current page/url also changes.

In my `app.js` where I define my routes for angular I also have a `.run` containing

```
history.pushState({}, 'Restaurants List', document.URL.match(/.+#\//).toString() + 'orders/restaurants')
```

this instantly will change my url from the intended target to the new history entry.

I've also tried using `replaceState` without any success.

A solution I've thought of is first changing the history then redirecting the user which works fine, but I want to avoid that additional overhead.

Is there any way to just add to the history without going to it so that if the user hits back it goes to a different page?

Comment: I am not sure it is possible in one simple command line. What you have to do is to catch $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess' event and change the rooting inside this function when you identify that the user is going back.

Comment: Hmm but then thats reliant on the user being on my page in the first place. I'm in a situation where our main website redirects to the angular app and I want to be sure when they click back they get redirected to an angular page

Comment: Just tested now : when you click "back" on your navigator, $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart' is fired even if you are your previouw URL is a "non angular" page.

Comment: really now, so then I just have to add logic for preventing them from going back? Even if I use `event.preventDefault()` is that enough to stop the browser from going back to a different webpage entirly?

Comment: Easier than that : in the ..$on(change... function, use the angular service $location to route where you want. Angular is a complete framework, it is good to do the things in the angular way (forget preventDefault except in directive, and do not use history native functions...)

Comment: @benek I just tried it. If your previous page is not part of the angular application. There is no $stateChangeStart event. I just used `$rootScope.on('$stateChangeStart', function() {debugger})`

Comment: May be you're right, not sure that angular is firing this event for unknown routes. Can you try also $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart' because $state is only used for UI Router.

Comment: and route would only be for angulars internal route system with NgRoute :/